# How to set Allow Automatic Updating feature for my app on Play store

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, auto-update

I observed some applications in play store are showing Allow Automatic Updating option with check box at the time of installation,some don't why? are there any settings or permissions to be added for this in manifest file or this is something available for preloaded apps or apps which has vendor/manufacturer certificate? What I have to do to get Allow Automatic Updating feature for my application on play store as a normal developer. Below Image showing what I am referring too. Any Suggestions please, Thanks In Advance.

[image]

[EDIT] just for Info

As a normal developer we can't implement this feature. The reason is android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES  is just ignored by Android system unless your app is signed with manufacturer certificate. If your app is certified with manufacturer certificate then your app is treated as part of firmware and it is eligible for silent installation of any packages.

Comment: This feature is from Android Play store itself, our apps has nothing to do with it. For Apps which are already in our device this option will come and for others once you click on install this option will automatically come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've published an application on Google Play and it has "Allow Automatic Update" checkbox.

I did not do anything special to make it available. If you have a sample of the application, which is published on Google Play and does not have this checkbox, please, let me know, since I haven't seen such an application yet.

Comment: What is the default setting?

Comment: I cannot find this checkbox, where is it please?